# Simple calculator C++ loop

Tags: c++, calc

I am a student in my first year.
Could someone help me with an assignment?

Simple calc C++

In the first line the number of tests n. In the next n lines operations Each operation contains the operation type (+ *) the number of k numbers to be processed, and k numbers

Output
Result

Example

Input

```
3
+ 3 3.1 5.2 -8.3
* 2 1 3.3
+ 1 3
```

Output

```
0
3.3
3
```

My code

```
    int n, k;
    char x;
    cin >> n;
    int tab[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> x >> k;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            cin >> tab[j];
            if (x == '+')
            {
                tab[j] += tab[j + 1];
            }
            if (x == '*')
            {
                tab[j] *= tab[j + 1];
            }
            cout << tab[j];
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What's your question? What problem are you having? Can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: please read [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) , you have to do your best at it, and if you get a specific coding problem while doing the assignment you can ask about it, and you'll have to include your code in the questions, simply asking people to do the assignment for you is against stack overflow guidelines.

Comment: there is an edit button under the question, and there is also a code `{}` button that will format your code, the code has to be in the question itself, and you have to ask a specific programming question, about a specific problem that you encountered.

Comment: II do not know who helped me to insert the code in the correct way. Include your code correctly the next time you ask. Thank you !!!

Comment: Numbers like `5.2` require a type other than `int` to store/read. Furthermore you don't need an array to store the values. Just store the neutral element into a variable and then read into a single variable in the loop and then apply combine the intermediate result with the value read. Note: the neutral element for both operations is different.

Comment: (1) Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). (2) If you have tried everything and it still doesn't work, learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: @fabian,

Could you demonstrate with the above example?
I am a beginner with programming. I does not want to give up at the beginning of school, needs an example to understand. Thank you.

Comment: The logic is flawed in several ways - walk through  the code or use a debugger with the example inputs and fix those you can, and ask more specific questions about those you cannot fix yourself.  Some examples of issues - The array `tab` serves no purpose, use an accumulator.  Output the result _after_ the inner loop, not within it.

Comment: I won't give you the exact results, but let's assume you want to concatenate strings, then the neutral element is the empty string, since you can append any string to the empty string and the result is still the string you appended. Assuming the input is the same except the iterator is always assumed to be concatenation you could write the loop as `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { char x; int k; cin >> x >> k; std::string result = ""; while(k > 0) { std::string val; std::cin >> val; result += val; --k; } std::cout << result << '\n'; }`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems.

1. your `tab` is of type `int` so it can only store integers e.g.: `1,2,3,4,5` not floating point numbers like `1.3 2.5 3.3`, you should consider changing `tab` to be of type `float`.
2. your loop logic and indexing is totally wrong, and you are accessing the wrong elements, you should have some sort of accumulator variable that will accumulate the results instead of storing them in an array. e.g.:

   ```
   float accumulator = 0; 
   cin >> input_number; 
   accumulator += input_number;`
   ```

the best advice i can give you is to learn to use the debugger, the debugger is your friend, you should use it to walk through your code, line by line and understand what each lines does to each variable, and read the contents of each variable, i cannot recommend a certain source for learning to use a debugger as it depends on your IDE, but you should maybe check a video on *using debugger with IDE X*, it can be a good start for learning to use an IDE GUI.

Answer (score 2):

The issues are many.  Just some:

- The purpose of `tab` is unclear.  You do not need to store the operands, you can accumulate a result in a single value.
- In any event `tab[j + 1];` is not initialised at point of use.
- If you want to output the results after all the input as indicated in the question then you do need somewhere to store the results for later output.
- You do need to output the results.
- The input and output types do need to be a floating-point type.

Greater clarity of thought might arise if you were to use clear variable names that reflected their purpose and perhaps some comments.  If you have to explain what the code does (even to yourself) often you spot the errors.  A good technique is to write the comments first, to explain what you need to code rather than explaining the code you have written and assume erroneously to be correct.  Also you need to get out of that "all variables at the top" habit.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Get number of calculations
    int ncalc = 0 ;
    std::cin >> ncalc ;

    // Create array for results
    double* result = new double[ncalc] ;
    
    // For each calculation
    for( int calc = 0; calc < ncalc; calc++ )
    {
        // Get the operator
        char op = 0 ;
        std::cin >> op ;
        
        // Get the number of operands
        int noperands = 0 ;
        std::cin >> noperands ;
        
        // Get initial operand in accumulator
        double accumulator = 0 ;
        std::cin >> accumulator ;

        // For each remaining operand...
        for( int i = 1; i < noperands; i++)
        {
            // Get the operand
            double operand = 0 ;
            std::cin >> operand ;

            // Perform the operation
            switch( op )
            {
                // For +, accumulate sum
                case '+' : accumulator += operand ; break ;

                // For * accumulate product
                case '*' : accumulator *= operand ; break ;
            }
        }

        // Store accumulated result
        result[calc] = accumulator ;
    }
  
    // Output results
    for( int calc = 0; calc < ncalc; calc++ )
    {
        std::cout << result[calc] << '\n' ;
    }

    delete[] result ;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See this run with @yougotproblems example input at https://onlinegdb.com/hGUkXJc-D